# Error in code about matrix resulting in segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault

Help! Another error that might be simple yet I cannot find the solution. The error message does not appear when compiling and there's no suggestion but I already tried many different ways. I'm new in programming.

```
#ifndef __MATRIX_H__
#define __MATRIX_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "Vector.h"
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int uint;

//Matrix class to handle basic linear algebra operations.
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        vector<vector<T> > elements;
        uint shape[2];

        // Constructors
        Matrix();
        Matrix(uint, uint);
        Matrix(vector<vector<T> >);
        Matrix(string);

        //Print vector elements.
        void print() const;

        //Print vector shape.
        void printshape() const;

        //Append a vector to the last row.
        void push_back(vector<T>);

        //Check if matrix has same shape to other matrix.
        bool has_same_shape(Matrix<T>&) const;

        //Save matrix to a text file with string filename as parameter.
        void savetext(string) const;

        //Indexing operator that returns the row as a Vector class.
        vector<T> operator[] (uint);

        //Comparison operator.
        bool operator== (Matrix<T>&);

        //Matrix transpose.
        Matrix<T> transpose();

        //Destructor.
        ~Matrix();

};

//Default Constructor.
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() {};

// Constructor for zero matrix with shape = num_row-by-num_col.
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(uint num_row, uint num_col){
    for(uint i = 0; i <= num_row; i++){
        for(uint j = 0; j <= num_col; j++){
            elements[i].push_back(0);
        }
    }
    shape[0] = num_row;
    shape[1] = num_col;
}
```

I did not include other part of the code because they're mostly empty/in comments yet

Comment: *I did not include other part of the code* -- You should include `main`.  Also: `#ifndef __MATRIX_H__` -- undefined behavior -- identifiers with leading underscores are reserved for the compiler's use.

Comment: two underscores in a row anywhere is also a potential kiss of death.

Answer (score 0):

In `elements[i].push_back(0);` your array access is out of bounds, because you never add anything to `elements`, so it is empty at this point.

A simple solution would be to add a new vector vector in the outer loop:

```
for(uint i = 0; i <= num_row; i++){
    //add new vector with emplace back
    elements.emplace_back();

    for(uint j = 0; j <= num_col; j++){
        elements[i].push_back(0);
    }
}
```